# Is there a way in chrome inspector to generate the dom selector

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome

Is it possible for me to generate the selector statement for an html class I want to manipulate in javascript.  I see that the class is present however when I try top.$find('.specific_class'); it returns null which makes me believe I am using the incorrect select statement.

Comment: You should use `$('.specific_class')` the method `find()` of jQuery is here to find sub elements matching a specific selector such as `$('body').find('.specific_class')`

Comment: If you select an element in the HTML view, then in the console you can refer to it as `$0`.  To wrap it in a jQuery object, you could then do `$($0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JQuery selector is not formatted correctly.

Try the following:

```
$(".specific_class").find(function(){                  

       // do your code here with this instance of the found .specific_class $(this)

       // get this items ID
       var id = $(this).attr("id");


});
```

Comment: So now I can use function(item){ alert(item.id) correct? Or would I use item.attr('id')? I am trying to return the unique id for the particular class.  Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

you can test if a selector is present by using `.length` - for example:

```
if($(".specific_class").length){
    //$(".specific_class") definitely exists, so now you can do something like:
    $(".specific_class").find(function(){
        //code
    });
}
```

Comment: Don't really need to test its length first - the `find` won't fire if there aren't any found.